# What do you make of these lines?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, knowledge

Can you recognize the lines below?

> Do you `utter` the `moniker` of your `emancipator` `during` your `time` of `requirement`?
>   And `experience` the `guilt` if the `character` should `bring back memories to` you of `avarice`.
>   Of `indication`, `incrimination` and `animosity`, till you cannot `rest` `motionless`,
>   In `the whole of` this `upheaval`, `prior to` `blood-coloured` `cloak` and `thin metal` `converge` for `an execution`.

Comment: @Bob: I would argue this isn't a trivia question, since all you have to do is find synonyms (some of which are obvious) and use Google. I'd never heard of that song, but got the answer just by Googling "in your hour of need till you cannot stay still".

Comment: I see your point but surely you could argue that about many trivia questions. Could this be solved without the magical power of the internet? (or knowledge of the song in this case)

Comment: @Bob I see your point as well, which is why I haven't rolled back your edit! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Maybe we need a new tag `search-engine-puzzle` -  like `computer-puzzle` but less technical knowledge required.

Comment: In either case, +1 for introducing me to something I had no awareness of.

Comment: @Bob I'd be against that, since _loads_ of puzzles could be solved by using a search engine. Lots of the maths and lateral-thinking puzzles are old chestnuts which are easy to find elsewhere on the web. It spoils the fun in a way!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace all the words in code formatting (if that's what it is) by

> synonyms of themselves,

thus turning the given lines into

> Do you `breathe` the `name` of your `saviour` `in` your `hour` of `need`,
>  And `taste` the `blame` if the `flavour` should `remind` you of `greed`?
>  Of `implication`, `insinuation` and `ill will`, till you cannot `lie` `still`,
>  In `all` this `turmoil`, `before` `red` `cape` and `foil` `come closing in` for `a kill`.

... which is the song

> ['Carnival of Rust' by the Finnish rock band Poets of the Fall](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/poetsofthefall/carnivalofrust.html).

Comment: You've got it. It's a song though, not a poem.